# Что значат константы INADDR_ANY и INADDR_LOOPBACK?

Tags: c++, сокет

Объясните пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю, что функции htonl/htons -  преобразовывают неупорядоченные байты в упорядоченные? И почему мы передаем аргументами константы, если адреса всегда разные? Не могу понять....
Есть еще вопросы: почему sin_addr - структура, если там только один тип данных?

```
if(bind(listener, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
{
        perror("bind");
        exit(2); 
}
```

Касательно кода выше три вопроса:

1. Выполняется ли привязка несмотря на то, что мы написали эту функцию в скобках? То есть мы же не в отдельной строке прописали эту функцию, не поставили точку с запятой, но она все равно выполнится?
2. Как происходит приведение типа данных sockaddr_in к sockaddr, если в первом случае структура состоит из 4 типов данных, а во втором всего из двух?
3. Правильно ли я понимаю, что bind - означает указать, на какой адрес будут приходить данные? Если да, то зачем это нужно, разве могут данные прийти куда то, кроме как на сервер? Или это реализовывается в крупных дата центрах, где много разных серверов, а мне достаточно сделать привязку по своему единственному айпишнику? Все, что будет приходить на адрес, привязанный к сокету, будет взаимодействовать с этим самым сокетом? А что, если несколько сокетов под таким адресом, то к какому из них придет пакет?

Comment: Функция `htonl` преобразует порядок байт в 32-разрядном числе из локального (обычно LittleEndian) в сетевой (BigEndian). Функция `htons` делает то же самое для 16-разрядного числа. Например, число `0xAABBCCDD` будет преобразовано в `0xDDCCBBAA`. Функция `bind`, да и любая другая, выполняется одинаково независимо от того, записана она в блоке `if` или нет.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что в локальной сети и интернет сетях используются разные айпишники, и htonl/htons нужны для того, чтобы сделать из локального айпишника - сетевой?

Comment: Нет, не разные. Функция `htonl` работает только с порядком байт в числе и не имеет никакого отношения к ip-адресу. Под локальным порядком байт подразумевается порядок хранения байт на локальном компьютере. Например, есть число `12548`. В шестнадцатеричном виде оно будет выглядеть так: `0x3104`. Но разработчики некоторых процессоров решили, что им удобнее хранить байты в обратном порядке, и это число будет представлено так: `0x04310000`. При передаче чисел по сети (хоть локальной, хоть интернет) принят порядок байт BigEndian, и поэтому его нужно преобразовать обратно к `0x00003104`.

Comment: Наконец то понял, спасибо большое

Comment: ip-адрес - частный случай 32-разрядного числа, и его так же можно преобразовывать из локального порядка в сетевой с помощью функции `htonl`. Функция сама проверяет, какой порядок байт применяется на локальной машине, и в зависимости от этого либо переворачивает число, либо нет.

Comment: Я запомню это, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. А как же? Конечно, выполнится. Иначе что будет сравниваться с нулем? :) Вот если вы напишете что-то типа `if (false && (bind(...) < 0))` — тогда дело другое из-за сокращенного вычисления логического выражения.
2. Знаете байку о том, что диаметр бака шаттла определяется шириной крупа древнеримской лошади? :) Вот примерно та же картина. Так сложилось исторически. Но это чисто мое личное мнение по данному вопросу.
3. Представьте, что у вас пара сетевых карт в машине, да еще и 127.0.0.1 имеется... Вот к какому интерфейсу "прибиндитесь", тот и прослушиваете. Будете слушать только loopback — и все, через сетевые карты к серверу будет не достучаться. Лучше всего — используйте `INADDR_ANY`, и прослушиваться будут *все* ваши интерфейсы. Несколько сокетов на один ip/port вы посадить не сможете, получите ошибку.

`htonl`/`htons` — "host to net" — функция, которая преобразует число (`l` или `s` — длинное или короткое) из представления на вашем компьютере (это может быть little endian или big endian, для того и функция, что она берет выяснение этого вопроса на себя) в сетевое представление, где используется big endian как единый стандарт обмена информацией между разными архитектурами.

Comment: Спасибо, что на первый мой самый вопрос ответили досконально, что на этот, нет слов, одни эмоции....